# Spark Worker could not find CassandraPartition Class

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, spark-cassandra-connector

I am working on spark standalone cluster with a master and 3 workers. 
My driver is also on the same network, so basically all the workers and master can communicate with the driver and vice-versa.

I am trying to do the job from the driver by getting the sparksession (in Java program). Maven dependencies added for the program are spark-core_2.11(v2.2), spark-sql_2.11(v2.2), spark-streaming_2.11(v2.2),spark-mllib_2.11(v2.2), spark-cassandra-connector_2.11(v2.0.5), spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11(v1.6.0-M1).

I am getting the following error in the slave.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1826)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
    java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Could someone help me in figuring out this issue...

Also, the launch command in slave looks like below:

```
17/11/15 03:21:07 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/docker-java-home/jre/bin/java"
     "-cp" "//conf/:/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M"
     "-Dspark.cassandra.connection.port=9042"
     "-Dspark.driver.port=7078"
     "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" 
     "--driver-url"
     "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@xx:xx:xx:xx:7078"
     "--executor-id" "10" "--hostname"
     "slave01" "--cores" "4"
     "--app-id" "app-20171115032101-0019" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@slave01:12125"
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the datastax spark cassandra connector dependency jars to the runtime classpath in spark workers.